# How to pause Python script and let user type in Linux terminal

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I'm making a Python script that automates some tasks in Linux.
The script installs some packages and, after the installation of this pacakges, i want the user to run some terminal commands. I was wondering if there is a way for do this by "Pausing" the script and by creating a direct comunication between the terminal and the user.

I know that there are other ways for do that like by writing an input statement in python and make an `os` call that run what the user typed like this

```py
from python import os

cmd = input('Type your command here: ')
os.system(cmd)
```

or by using some `subrocess` functions in the same way

```py
import subprocess

cmd = input('Type your command here: ')
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output, errors = p.communicate()
```

But there is a way for create a comunication between the terminal and the user while the script is running without the necessity to open a new terminal?

Comment: Why do you want to get input from the terminal instead of getting the input through `input()` function?

Comment: Just for know is possible to do in that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just start a shell session:

```
os.system('/bin/sh')
```

Comment: brilliant. @Mat.C this is your solution. to go back to the script just exit this new shell